# Improving tesseract ocr result in french

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to perform OCR on a image that is fairly clean and "easy" for OCR I think:

[image]

But the result using tesseract is quite bad:

```
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('file-2.jpg'),lang='fra'))

Maintenant ie La QT vieux, lorsque
je parcours un cimetière, j'ai
l'impression de Dares CT
LT TTC
```

Why is that? Can I improve the result?

When I use an online OCR tool the result is perfect.

Comment: You should invert the image to dark text on light background, and converting the image to gray scale or 2-bit B/W might help further. The more contrast the better.

Comment: "When I use an online OCR tool the result is perfect." OK, but that's not really helpful unless you know what the OCR tool is doing.